# How can I make this code more efficient? loops and Big Data

Tags: java, performance, hadoop, mapreduce, analytics

I just learned to code few months back, but my project actually is very heavy for what I already know, any help making this code run more efficient would be appreciated.

What I'm trying to do is make this code more efficient because **it took 20 hours to process a 30 MB file, and I want to process a 6.5 GB worth of files.** I need it to process the file in 30 minutes maximum ... is that possible?

**What I'm doing in the code is**:

1. I extract a word and check if it's ID is stored into my hashmap
2. I get all the parents of this word and add them to a list
3. In each item on the list I get the ID and Word and other parents
4. I create a node and add it to the hashmap
5. Then move on ot the next word

P.S. I do not know how to do Hadoop MapReduce code, I know it's the obvious solution ... but I don't have the time to learn it.

**UPDATE!!**
[As you see in the Screenshot, **99.7% time was used to "getInstance" of the word from the WordNet dictionary**, which is the library I'm using: extjWNl. "getResourceInstance" is method that calls the dictionary itself, and the third highlighted entry is my method that calls these methods (only 0.001% of the time is actually spent by the rest of the method)

I am not sure if this issue is solvable, or do you have any ideas? - Click this "1" for Screenshot][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPw8k.png)

```
    static HashMap<Long, Node> graph = new HashMap <Long, Node> ();

    private static void demonstrateTree (IndexWord word) throws JWNLException {

        Long Os = word.getSenses().get(0).getOffset();

        if (graph.containsKey(Os)) {
            return;
        }

        PointerTargetTree hypernyms = PointerUtils.getHypernymTree(word.getSenses().get(0));
        List<PointerTargetNodeList> hypernymsList = hypernyms.toList();

        for(int c=0;c<hypernymsList.size();c++){

            PointerTargetNodeList l = hypernymsList.get(c);

            for(int j = l.size()-1; j >= 0 ; j--) {

                Long tempid = l.get(j).getPointerTarget().getSynset().getOffset();
                String tempword = l.get(j).getPointerTarget().getSynset().getWords().get(0).getLemma();
                Node n = new Node(tempid, tempword, new ArrayList<Node>());

                if (!graph.containsKey(tempid)) {

                    n.id = tempid;
                    n.word = tempword;

                    if (!(j == l.size()-1)){
                        n.parents.add(graph.get(l.get(j+1).getPointerTarget().getSynset().getOffset()));
                    }
                    graph.put(tempid, n);
                }       
            }
        }
    }

    public static void demonstrateListHelper(String text) throws JWNLException {

        String lineText =text.split("\t")[2];
        String [] singleWord = lineText.split("\\s+");
        for (int k=0; k <singleWord.length; k++){

            singleWord[k] = singleWord[k].replaceAll("[^\\w]", "");
            IndexWordSet set = Dictionary.getDefaultResourceInstance().lookupAllIndexWords(singleWord[k]);

            for (IndexWord word:set.getIndexWordArray()) {
                demonstrateTree(word);
            }
        }   
    }

    public static void generateHierarchy() {

        Set<Entry<Long, Node>> iterator = graph.entrySet();
        int i =0;
        for(Entry<Long,Node> e : iterator) {
            System.out.println(i++ +" - " +e.getValue().firstParents());
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "resource" })
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JWNLException {
        File file = new File("C:/Users/D060891/Desktop/Thesis/sentencesNYT/part-m-00001");

        try {

            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;

            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                demonstrateListHelper(line);                              
            }
            generateHierarchy();
        }

        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is possible depending on what you code does. You can read text at 100 MB/s, but what you do with that data is likely to matter more.

Comment: have you used profiler to profile your code? which part of your code takes the greatest amount of time to execute?

Comment: just for information purposes: [Profiling in Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/documents/tutorials/profilingtool/profilingexample_32.html), and [Netbeans profiler](https://profiler.netbeans.org/)

Comment: In your code you are trying to create a tree based on the column in the data?
More info on data example and output will help

Comment: I will run this profiler and see what I get, I'll edit the post with the updates. As regards to what I'm doing, I'll edit in the question as well.

Comment: Done ... was a bit unexpected ... I thought the problem was with my loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first rule of performance optimization is to not stare at code or guess but measure runtime behaviour. So fire up a profiler and see where your program spends the time (or the memory).

A good start would be to [profile](http://visualvm.java.net/profiler.html) your code with [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/docindex.html) which is included in the JDK.

**Update:**
You now have identified the bottleneck:

```
Dictionary.getDefaultResourceInstance()
```

Looking into the [source code](https://github.com/extjwnl/extjwnl/blob/master/extjwnl/src/main/java/net/sf/extjwnl/dictionary/Dictionary.java#L191) a wordnet dictionary is loaded from a XML doc every time you call that method. So simply move the bottleneck **out of the loop** and get the Dictionary **once** at the beginning: Define a class variable

```
private static Dictionary dictionary;
```

initialize at the beginning, e.g. in main

```
dictionary = Dictionary.getDefaultResourceInstance();
```

and then use it later

```
dictionary.lookupAllIndexWords(singleWord[k]);
```

Comment: Thank you sir, you are such a life saver!

now I actually know how to figure out problems with my efficiency! Being a new coder is a bit tough to be honest.

Comment: @AhmedAmmar you are welcome. Now that you have mastered the art of profiling you are no longer a newbie coder!